# Spring MVC AngularJS No mapping found

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

I've been following the tutorial for integrating [Spring Security with AngularJS](https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-security-and-angular-js/), but it uses Spring Boot. I can get the tutorial examples working, but I need my app to run as a regular MVC application under Tomcat.

The problem is getting the application to route to the index.html page for the initial view. The only mappings I have in the controllers are the REST calls I want to receive from Angular, but I can't seem to get the application to go to the index page. Spring Boot does this automatically, but I'm going to run this as a web app under Tomcat. Trying to go there directly causes a 'No mapping found' error.

I'm using Java configuration and have the antMatchers, etc as described in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are a few entries in my config classes to make this happen.

```
    @Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/index.html", "/home.html", "/login.html", "/").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/user").permitAll().anyRequest()
            .authenticated().and()
            .csrf()
            .csrfTokenRepository(csrfTokenRepository()).and()
            .addFilterAfter(csrfHeaderFilter(), CsrfFilter.class);

    if ("true".equals(System.getProperty("httpsOnly"))) {
        LOGGER.info("launching the application in HTTPS-only mode");
        http.requiresChannel().anyRequest().requiresSecure();
    }
}




@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.mygroupnotifier.controller")
public class ServletContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/js/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/*.html").addResourceLocations("/resources/static/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
}
```

}

As usual the most difficult part of this is getting the leading and ending / on the classes and the html files.